# Storing all possible Set values in an array?

Tags: php, mysql

Can you guys find anything wrong with this php code? I always get the "Error: Could not show columns" message, but when I try the query "show columns from recipes like 'Book'" in the MySQL Command Line Client it works just fine.

I got this code snippet from one of the comments in the section on Sets in the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html). It's supposed to get all possible values of a Set and store them in an array.

```
<?php
    $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM recipes LIKE 'Book'";
    if (!($ret = mysql_query($query)))
        die("Error: Could not show columns");
    $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($ret);
    $set = $line['Type'];
    $set = substr($set,5,strlen($set)-7);
    $options = preg_split("/','/",$set);
?>
```

Perhaps there is another way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you edit your die statement, you can cause it to reveal some useful information: `die("Could not show columns<br>" . mysql_error());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you haven't selected a database using `mysql_select_db`.

Try changing your `die` statement to:

```
die("Error: Could not show columns - ". mysql_error());`
```

Make sure to remove this before moving your code to production.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I tried adding a call to mysql_select_db and it worked. Thank you!